# Resolve "missing relationships" message

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I get the "relationships between tables may be needed" message in Excel 2016 PowerPivot. I suspect this is because I've got a many-to-many relationship, but lack experience to be sure. I'll be happy to read up on it if someone can help me put a name on the problem.

The data that I'm analyzing looks like this:

**Units** - Instances of a product. E.g. the computer was produced 100 times = 100 units. Each unit has ONE ProductID, and a UnitID (unique). Units have e.g. a production time.

**Products** - Each product can consist of several items. A product could be computer xyz = "laptop xyz, driver CD, manual, power brick, 2 chocolates and mains cable". Each product has a unique ProductID and an PackListID. Several products can have the same PackListID.

**PackList** - Unique PackListIDs

**CompositeList** - for each PackListID, this can contain several ItemIDs and number included in packing list (e.g. 2 pieces of chocolate)

**Items** - line items for a product packing list, e.g. "manual for computer xyz"

I want to answer the question: How many (compositelist.number) line items of each Items have been included in units produced on a particular date (units.date).

I read the data by SQL from a existing application/database server. I cannot influence how the data is structured :(

I've imported my data and connected as follows:
Unit.ProductID -> Product.ProductID (each product can have many units)

Product.PackListID -> PackList.PackListID (bridge table)

PackList.PackListID -> CompositeList.PackListID (each packlist can have many composite-rows)

CompositeList.ItemID -> Items.ItemID (each composite-list refers to one item)

If I filter by PackListID, the result is a correct list of line items with sums.
Now I'd like to multiply that with the number of times that packlist has been produced on a particular day...

My pivot looks like this:
**Filter**: Production date, filter to a particular date
**Rows**: Items.text
**Values**: Sum of compositelist.number

I would love to see the number of line items used in production on a certain day, e.g. 15 manuals and 32 mains cables.

Unfortunately I get the message "Relationships between tables may be needed".

Comment: Is this on the pivot table menu? If so you can safey ignore this message.

Comment: Thanks, but the results are clearly not correct. I get the same result, no matter which day I pick - and they differ in production

Comment: Can you post your measures? (I assume you're using measures for the pivot value with the tables as filters to a calculate [https://powerpivotpro.com/2012/11/a-mystifying-and-awesome-solution-for-many-2-many/]?) Any chance you could upload an image of the relationship so it's a bit easier to see.

Comment: Sorry for not replying. I decided to go around the problem for the moment, and solved it with a SQL-query instead. Thanks for trying to help :)